# Using the Square API and the IOS SDK is it possible to create a request with separate taxable and nontaxable amounts?

Tags: ios, square-connect

I have successfully integrated the Square IOS SDK into my app.  I would like to create an SCCAPIRequest which specifies an amount to be taxed and an amount to not be taxed, in my case labor.  I haven't seen any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up your taxes inside the Square Point of Sale app, and if you don't override them with `clearsDefaultFees` they will automatically be applied to your transaction.

Partial taxation like you described is not currently possible. You can calculate the total yourself and pass that instead.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like the workaround would be to launch Square twice, once for taxable and once for nontaxable.

Comment: It could be, depending on your use case. If that was customer facing it might be a little strange to have to use your card twice. I was suggesting that you calculate the total of taxable and non-taxable charges on your app, and then creating a charge request for the total.